# Why is this HTTP POST failing?

Tags: http, post

I am trying to make a HTTP POST request but it keeps failing. Is anything wrong with the request? Is it missing anything or is there anything that should be removed?

```
POST /add_file HTTP/1.1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=463762444806
Host: BuzWebServer

--463762444806
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="demo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

demo text blah blah blah
--463762444806--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very important header was missing, the Content-Length header